# Importing and using the google-cloud-storage module in appengine standard environment

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I have installed [google-cloud-storage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-storage) to my `lib` folder in my appengine project. Then, in my `appengine_config.py` file, I have:

`import sys
import os.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))`

`appengine_config.py` and `lib` (a directory), are children in the same parent directory.

With that, I would expect that appengine will load the library. However, when I do an import in my `main.py` file like `from google.cloud import storage`, I get an import error like so: `ImportError: No module named google.cloud.storage`.

Is it possible to use a third party library like that in the appengine standard environment. If yes, how? If no, would you kindly explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible to use `google-cloud-storage` in Appengine Standard Environment. I'm able to use `google-cloud-translate` the way you describe. However, your `appengine_config.py` does not seem to be correct. Try this:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

Assuming that your `lib` folder and `appengine_config.py` file are located in the same folder.

---

**NOTE**
I had though need to add the following to `appengine_config.py` file in order to prevent `ImportError: No module named pwd` error.

```
import os.path

def patched_expanduser(path):
    return path

os.path.expanduser = patched_expanduser
```

According to [this post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/626#issuecomment-257347967).